# Readline stops working randomly

Tags: bash, zsh, iterm2, readline

For some reason every 1-3 hours (depending on work load) my shell `read` command stops accepting input and hitting return renders the `^M` character. Something like:

```
Continue?
```

After answering:

```
Continue? y^M
```

I did a diff of the environment variables (set) before and after the problem, but could not find a cause, neither can I reproduce of find out if the problem is my shell (zsh) or terminal program (iTerm)

What can cause `read` to stop working?

Comment: Maybe the terminal is set to raw input mode. To confirm this, you can compare the output of `stty`.

Comment: thanks! that would be an accepted answer. Something is setting randomly  `-icrnl` on my stty, now the challenge is finding what is doing that.